# Have a proxy repository in bintray from another repository

Tags: maven, repository, nexus, artifactory, bintray

I try to find out if it is possible to have a private maven repository (nexus, artifactory) run on the net to be proxied to my bintray account. Anybody did this or is aware of such functionality?

Answer (score 1):

`Artifactory` provides you with the ability to proxy Bintray repositories using [Remote Repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Remote+Repositories), so the short answer is yes.

The longer answer is that both Bintray and Artifactory were made by the same company, so they are a perfect match for each other.

Artifactory can proxy any type of repository from Bintray (not just `Maven`) and also provides extensive integration for achieving the opposite direction (i.e. publishing Artifacts to Bintray from Artifactory) using [Distribution Repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Distribution+Repository).
You can read more about the various Bintray integration options Artifactory provides [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Bintray+Integration).

Comment: Thanks for responding! My question was referring to the opposite direction: I want to have a proxy of my nexus/artifactory repository in bintray. I see no option to solve this, apart from writing some separate synchronisation using the bintray api.

Comment: Bintray is not meant to serve as a proxy to services but provide a central location for downloads - that being said, Artifactory's [Distribution Repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Distribution+Repository) functionality that I  mentioned in my answer will give you just that